# How can the derivative of ln(x) be defined for values of x that are undefined for ln(x) itself?

Tags: calculus

$y=\ln(x)$ is only defined for positive values of $x$. Yet the derivative of $y=\ln(x)$ is $y'=1/x$, which is defined everywhere except when $x$ is zero.

How can this be?

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of $\ln{x}$ is $1/x$ only when $x > 0$. When $x < 0$, $1/x$ is the derivative of $\ln(-x)$.

Many calculus books will combine these two cases and say that the derivative of $\ln|x|$ is $1/x$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense- thanks